# Почему образуется пустое пространство между дивом и вложенным iframe?

Tags: css

Необходимо обвести карту рамкой. Обернул iframe дивом, с соответствующим стилем. И почему-то между нижней границе фрейма и div'ом образуется пустое пространство.
[image]

Как можно от него избавиться?

```
<div class='blue-bord'>
 <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m12!1m3!1d29809712.482889578!2d94.1439049039685!3d62.86936133664777!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1sru!2sru!4v1406285610084" width="100%" height="400" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
</div>  


 .blue-bord{
   border: 1px solid #009fe3;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/ZfSE2/

http://jsfiddle.net/A5cay/

Comment: Таким образом работает. Но только при фиксированной высоте. А если оборачивается "резиновый" элемент? Ширина и высота которого изменяется.

Comment: добавил аддаптивный вариант